# Gnome Shell: Running shell script after session starts?

Tags: gnome3, desktop-environment, gnome-shell

I'm a long time KDE user, never seen GNOME since may be Mandrake Linux 10 something. Yesterday I took a look at GNOME Shell on Youtube and thought it may worth a look.

It actually is worth, but I can't figure out one moment.

I've got a shell script that used to run on my KDE Laptop installations for ages:

```
synclient |grep -E 'TapT|RightB|EdgeScr'|awk '{print $1}'|while read item; do synclient $item=0; done
synclient VertScrollDelta=-111
synclient HorizScrollDelta=1
synclient RightEdge=999999999
synclient TopEdge=0
synclient CircularScrolling=0
synclient BottomEdge=999999999
synclient RightButtonAreaLeft=9999999
synclient ClickFinger3=2
synclient HorizScrollDelta=0
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
```

This disables right-click, all taps, inverts scroll directions, disables horizontal scrolling and stuff. Touchpad menu nor in KDE neither in gnome doesn't allow this kind of configuration. (TBH, only Mac of all the operating systems has the gui to set up touchpad exactly like that :)).

I can't figure out, how do I run this after gnome shell session starts?
I've already tried this with no results:

```
[1] % cat /home/neko/.config/autostart/script.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name="Auto stuff"
GenericName="Auto startup stuff"
Comment="Synclient mostly"
Exec=/home/neko/bin/auto_stuff.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-Gnome-Autostart=true
```

Any other suggestions,please?
Thank you.

Comment: Is that `.desktop` file executable?

Comment: I've had no idea that .desktop files should've executable permissions. :)

Comment: The local (user) launchers, yeah, they have to be `+x`. Open `~/.config/autostart` in Nautilus and double click your `script.desktop`, you will be prompted to _"mark as trusted"_ (which is equivalent to `chmod +x`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the program gnome-session-properties.  Just execute it from your shell prompt (gnome-terminal):

`$ gnome-session-properties`

This will open a GUI where you can configure (i.e., add, edit, remove, enable and disable) startup programs.

Nice and easy.  Enjoy.

Update: As noted by don_crissti (thanks) in the comments below, the gnome-session-properties startup programs functionality has migrated to `gnome-tweak-tool` since Gnome 3.12 (which btw is a great tool, but a little messier as it concentrates just too many functions).  So, for versions 3.12 and above, this is the new place to look.

OBS: And btw, using this method, you don't need to create a `.desktop` file, you can simply specify the command line of the `/home/neko/bin/auto_stuff.sh` script you created (or any other script or command you want).

Comment: Worth noting that the `gnome-session-properties` binary is no longer present in recent Gnome 3 releases (removed as of `3.12` IIRC). Its [functionality was included](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=708923) in `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Comment: Interesting... I'm using Fedora 20 (with Gnome 3.10), which still has it.  Sad that the Gnome team continuously cripple (or shape) the software against users' taste.  At least they kept the functionality in gnome-tweak-tool, so here is it the new place to look...

Comment: gnome-tweak-tools does not allow you to add scripts at a specific location. You need to jump through hoops with desktop files.

Comment: However, gnome-session-properties is still working at least in ubuntu gnome 17.04; just start it from a shell.

Comment: and gnome-session-properties writes a .desktop entry for you in ~/.config/autostart

Comment: @TimRichardson, Yes, but you don't have to write your own. Anyway, gnome-session-properties is now kind of obsolete (considering latest distributions versions, at least for Fedora). Still it is/was a nice tool.

Comment: Hi @Marcelo for me, (Ubuntu 17.04) I could not find any UI element in gnome-tweak-tool which lets me enter command line scripts or even browse for them. Maybe Gnome on Ubuntu is a bit behind, even though it's mostly 3.24. This could be why gnome-session-properties is still available. I am new to gnome, migrating from xfce. From what I can see, gnome-tweak-tool doesn' have anything like the functionality of gnome-session-properties when it comes to startup scripts and it is weird how hard it seems to be.

Answer (score 3):

In `.desktop` files the [case is significant](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s03.html#entries). The following template works under Fedora 27 with GNOME shell (i.e. the `Exec=` value is executed during session start):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=/path/to/myscript arg1
Name=myscript
Comment=script some stuff
Terminal=false
OnlyShowIn=GNOME
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

(to be stored as `$HOME/.config/autostart/myscript.desktop`)

The main difference: you used the key `X-Gnome-Autostart=` in your example.

Double check if your script `/path/to/myscript` is executable, i.e. if it has the e**x**ecutable permission bit(s) set.

The `OnlyShowIn=` is perhaps not significant for the autostart functionality, but I haven't tested it without it. You can list multiple desktop environments like this: `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;LXDE;Unity;` Consult the `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` environment variable to verify correct values.

If you want to check whether your script prints any error messages you can check `journalctl --user`, i.e. the session journal.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to use  `chmod +x myscript.desktop /path/to/myscript.sh` as suggested in a comment. Otherwise *journalctl --user* would give the error `Could not parse desktop file myscript.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary`.

Comment: @sergio, sure, the `/path/to/myscript.sh` you want to exec has to be executable. But `myscript.desktop` does **not** need to have executable permissions.