# Mute all sound when locking device

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio, gnome-shell

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04, though I'd like to have a way to completely mute sound when I lock my device, this is for 2 differents situations: 
First avoid someone to unplug my headset and listen to what I was listening to.
Second to avoid my coworkers being annoyed by sound that might come out from my headset if a music is not mixed properly and suddenly shout out.
My goal is to not only mute but reliably avoid sound getting out of my computer when it is locked.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/974199/how-to-run-a-script-at-screen-lock-unlocks-in-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: Hum interesting, I'll have a look, thank you .

Answer (score 0):

`pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle`

or 

`pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle`

 if have only one audio sink

if there are multiple sinks, use 

`pactl list short sinks`

for list of sinks sorted by index number

Comment: ok it's part of the answer thank you for the hint. I have to find a way to disable keyboard shortcut because mute working but the keyboard can still raise sound level.

Comment: you did not mention a laptop with volume keys, or any other relevant hardware information. suggest you read `man amixer` and try similar mute toggle command for ALSA

Answer (score 0):

[How to mute sound when xscreensaver locks screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467456/how-to-mute-sound-when-xscreensaver-locks-screen/589614#589614)

Nicely mutes and un-mutes lock and unlock. I dunno which is better amixer Vs pactl.

```
#!/bin/bash

gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 | grep LockedHint --line-buffered |
    while read line
    do
        case "$line" in
            *"<true>"*)
                #amixer -q -D pulse sset Master off
                pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle
            ;;
            *"<false>"*)
                #amixer -q -D pulse sset Master on
                pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle
            ;;
        esac
    done
exit
```

Thanks to all (Nick Gnomic and Cliff Stanford).

Works without xscreensaver installed, confirm works on wayland as well.